# is there a way to select every single element in cheerio?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, dom, cheerio

Is there a way to get a cheerio object that contains every single element in a html page inclusive of children and then iterate through that?

I have tried using the object `$('body')` but it only gives the direct children of the HTML body, and not all subsequent children. Is there anything I can do to select all of the HTML elements, as I would like to parse the text of each individual element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `$('*')` ?

Or without using jQuery, just pure JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Ir returns a full array will all DOM elements